# Enable http header logging for envoy in istio

Tags: logging, kubernetes, http-headers, istio, envoyproxy

I want to be able to capture (log) (at least some of) `envoy`'s HTTP headers on my `istio` service mesh.

I have gone through `envoy`'s [docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/quick-start/run-envoy#debugging-envoy), and in the log levels' section, it does not mention any header-specific information.

Currently, my `istio-proxy` log is like this (this is from a `stern` output):

```
mysvc-69c46fbc75-d9v8j istio-proxy {"bytes_sent":"124","upstream_cluster":"inbound|80|http|mysvc.default.svc.cluster.local","downstream_remote_address":"10.11.11.1:0","authority":"some.url.com","path":"/health?source=dd_cluster_agent","protocol":"HTTP/1.1","upstream_service_time":"1","upstream_local_address":"127.0.0.1:40406","duration":"2","upstream_transport_failure_reason":"-","route_name":"default","downstream_local_address":"10.11.32.32:20000","user_agent":"Datadog Agent/7.24.0","response_code":"200","response_flags":"-","start_time":"2021-01-17T18:54:57.449Z","method":"GET","request_id":"61ae63c7-aa10-911b-9562-939kdhd49ddhj","upstream_host":"127.0.0.1:20000","x_forwarded_for":"10.16.32.1","requested_server_name":"outbound_.80_.mysvc_.faros.default.svc.cluster.local","bytes_received":"0","istio_policy_status":"-"}
```

Is there a way to log `http` headers? (ideally **some** of them, to keep the logging cost under control)

**edit1** following advice in the comments, I checked my `istio-operator` resource and I see that access logging seems to be enabled

```
    meshConfig:
      accessLogEncoding: JSON
      accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
```

**edit2** I have also tried the following:

```
curl -i -H "Custom-Header: application/json" https://my.url.net
```

but in the logs of the `istio-ingressgateway` I don't see my custom header

```
istio-ingressgateway-58f69d8696-rmpwn istio-proxy {"user_agent":"curl/7.64.1","response_code":"200","response_flags":"-","start_time":"2021-01-18T19:02:48.645Z","method":"GET","request_id":"8e32c93c-484d-9c56-9489-8c5392793d97","upstream_host":"10.16.32.55:20000","x_forwarded_for":"10.16.32.1","requested_server_name":"my.url.net","bytes_received":"0","istio_policy_status":"-","bytes_sent":"124","upstream_cluster":"outbound|80||mysvc.default.svc.cluster.local","downstream_remote_address":"10.16.32.1:52804","authority":"my.url.net","path":"/","protocol":"HTTP/2","upstream_service_time":"9","upstream_local_address":"10.16.32.17:49826","duration":"10","upstream_transport_failure_reason":"-","route_name":"-","downstream_local_address":"10.16.32.17:8443"}
```

Comment: Have you tried with [envoy access logging](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/)? Also you should be able to check the http headers with either [jaeger/zipkin](https://istio.io/latest/faq/distributed-tracing/) or some [lua script](https://github.com/kenju/service-mesh-patterns/tree/c22ae3850c2b34515c88a91459542af872d55e24/envoy-lua-filters).

Comment: thanks for the fdeedback Jakub, however I just checked and it seems to be enabled; see my update on the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've succesfully made a reproduction of your issue and I was able to print `MY_CUSTOM_HEADER` in the ingress gateway logs.

There is a part of my istio ingress gateway logs.

```
[2021-01-20T08:26:18.587Z] pkarambol GET /productpage HTTP/1.1 200
```

I've used below curl command:

```
curl -v -H "MY_CUSTOM_HEADER: pkarambol" xx.xxx.xx.xxx/productpage
```

---

To make that happen you have to change the [default format](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/observability/access_log/usage?fbclid=IwAR0xaS-EtEniJfbpGWf-GN_o75aLSpyn5FI2Uojp9YPWQD4PjQqs9ObqavQ#default-format-string) of the logs. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/#enable-envoy-s-access-logging), you can use `meshConfig.accessLogFormat` to change that.

---

There is an example of [Istio Operator](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/operator/) I've used.

`%REQ(MY_CUSTOM_HEADER)%` is a part responsible for displaying the custom header.

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: example-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: demo
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    accessLogFormat: "[%START_TIME%] %REQ(MY_CUSTOM_HEADER)% %REQ(:METHOD)% %REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)% %PROTOCOL%
%RESPONSE_CODE% %RESPONSE_FLAGS% %BYTES_RECEIVED% %BYTES_SENT% %DURATION%
%RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)% %REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)% %REQ(USER-AGENT)%
%REQ(X-REQUEST-ID)% %REQ(:AUTHORITY)% %UPSTREAM_HOST%\n"
```

Comment: Thanks `Jakub` I had come to the same conclusion; I was stuck however by the fact that a) I see in my `istio-proxy` logs some fields not existing in the so called default format, e.g. `istio_policy_status: "-"`; so I was trying to find a way to append to the existing log structure and not override it; I can't seem to find where `istio` adds filed that do not exist in the `defailt format`

Comment: actually since this is a good answer you provided, I will accept it and follow up with my new inquiry on a new SO question (which I will post here fyi)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815085/istio-somehow-overriding-default-access-logging-format-of-envoy fyi